# Aligning an structure to reduce the cache hits?

Tags: c, caching, memory-alignment

I want to improve the data locality of the following structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct double16{
    double v0;
    double v1;
    double v2;
    double v3;
    double v4;
    double v5;
    double v6;
    double v7;
    double v8;
    double v9;
    double v10;
    double v11;
    double v12;
    double v13;
    double v14;
    double v15;
};/* expected size is 128 bytes*/

// test - padding within a single struct,
int test_struct_padding() {
    printf("%s: %ld\n", "double16", sizeof(struct double16));
    return 0;
}

// test - address of struct,
int test_struct_address() {
    printf("%s: %ld\n", "double16", sizeof(struct double16));

    struct double16 dd;
    struct double16 ee;

    printf("address of %s: %p\n", "dd", &dd);

    // dd is only 128 bytes itself, but distance to next struct is 128 bytes(on 64 bit system)
    printf("space between %s and %s: %ld\n", "dd", "ff", (long)(&ee) - (long)(&dd));

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    test_struct_padding();
    test_struct_address();

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
double16: 128
double16: 128
address of dd: 0x7ff7bb3c8540
space between dd and ff: 128
```

In what way can I use packing and alignment to reduce as much as possible the number of cache hits? I do know that the size of the cache line on my computer is 64 which is half the size of the structure (you can get this information on `macos` using the command `sysctl hw.cachelinesize`). If someone knows how to measure experimentally the cache hits, a detailed explanation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: On the one hand, you say you want to `"make cache-frendly the following structure"`, on the other hand you state that you want to `"reduce the cache hits"`. These two statements seem contradictory. Is it your intention to reduce [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing), so that when two different threads access two different structures on the same cache line, there is no performance degredation?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I understand your point.  What I want is to reduce the cache hits. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unknown** if this helps cache hits, but here is how to control alignment and some packing.

You can **increase the alignment** strictness of an object:

```
#include <stdalign.h>

// struct double16 dd;
alignas(128) struct double16 dd;
```

Code can make reasonably certain `dd` and `ee` are adjacent in memory.

```
//struct double16 dd;
//struct double16 ee;
alignas(128) struct {
  struct double16 dd;
  struct double16 ee;
} u;
```

To make certain, use an array:

```
alignas(128) struct double16 ddee[2];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. However, if the cache cache line size of my computer is 64 why are you using  `alignas(128) struct double16 dd;`?

Comment: I just want to understand the rationale of your answer.

Comment: @user3116936 I am showing _how_ to perform a select alignment.  Use 64, 126, 256, etc.  If is unknown to me what is best for your case.

Comment: @user3116936 You [secretly] _know_ your cache line size is 64. Suppose you _didn't_ know. Aligning to `sizeof(struct double16)` (which is 128) does no harm and may produce better results if (e.g.) your cache line size was 128. Your build process could get the cache line size (e.g. from `/proc/cpuinfo` on linux) and use that as a `#define MY_CACHE_LINE_SIZE ...` and do `alignas(MY_CACHE_LINE_SIZE)`. This would reduce to _two_ cache lines instead of _three_ (if it was totally unaligned).

Comment: I understand better now. Thanks a lot to all of you.